# KerberosException: Unsupported enc type: 18

Tags: kerberos

Colleagues, good day,

After the cipher method was increased to aes256 we started to receive the following stacktrace related to Kerberos:

```
Caused by: com.dstc.security.kerberos.KerberosException: Unsupported enc type: 18
    at com.dstc.security.kerberos.KerberosCipher.getInstance(KerberosCipher.java:73)
    at com.dstc.security.kerberos.APReqImpl.initDecrypt(APReqImpl.java:215)
    at com.dstc.security.kerberos.Kerberos.decryptApplicationRequest(Kerberos.java:1375)
    at com.dstc.security.kerberos.gssapi.ServerHandShaker.authenticateClient(ServerHandShaker.java:282)
    at com.dstc.security.kerberos.gssapi.ServerHandShaker.handle(ServerHandShaker.java:209)
    at com.dstc.security.kerberos.gssapi.GSSContext.acceptSecContext(GSSContext.java:322)
```

How shall we tune `Kerberos` at client to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

> How shall we tune Kerberos at client to remove this error?

You don't; it's a service-side issue. If you've marked the service account as "supporting aes256", then that service must in fact have aes256 keys in its keytab (if it uses a keytab), and it must use a Kerberos library with aes256 support.